# How to find the minima for $y = x^2 + a.x - \lfloor\sqrt{x^2+a.x - b}\rfloor^2$?

Tags: derivatives, optimization, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Please guide in how to find the value of $x$ for which $y = x^2 + a.x - \lfloor\sqrt{x^2+a.x - b}\rfloor^2$ will be minimum.

I know this involves differentiation but am not sure on how to differentiate $\lfloor\sqrt{x^2+a.x - b}\rfloor^2$.

Comment: The expression $g(x)=\lfloor \sqrt{x^2+ax-b} \rfloor^2$ has $g'(x)=0$ wherever it exists because it is integer-valued. $g'$ will fail to exist where $g$ has jumps. Do you have specific values for $a$ and $b$? The domain of the function will depend on $a$ and $b$ since the expression $g(x)$ will not be defined wherever $x^2+ax-b<0$.

Comment: I need to find a way to minimise $y$ for any pair of $(a,b)$ where $a > 0, b > 0, x^2 + ax - b > 0$ and would like to better understand the way to do this. For working out the problem we can use $a = 2047$ and $b = 80$.